# Parsing Text data and converting the parsed data into dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, dataframe, parsing

I have a Text data and I want to parse the content and extract the Brand, MPN, Condition, Qty, Price, Customer name.

The text data is in the format:

```
---ABB INSTALLATION PRODUCT---

54905BE06, NEW, qty 1687, $1.05, ABB INSTALLATION PRODUCT, *#6 1 hole
5490 Searched by: Gracile IT LLC
    Oliver Wilson P:123 456 7890
 
---ARUBA NETWORKS---

R1C72A, NEW, qty 21, $155.00, ARUBA NETWORKS, *AP mount bracketAruba
R1C72A Searched by: Synergy Associates, LLC
    N/A P:123 456 7890
 
---ATC CENTRAL SOURCING---

3X5HZYLBACKCOX, NEW, qty 353, $8.24, ATC CENTRAL SOURCING, The ATC Ce
3X Searched by: Golden Gate Communications
    Mike Sweiss P:123 456 7890
 
3X5HZYLPWRCOX, NEW, qty 353, $8.24, ATC CENTRAL SOURCING, The ATC Cen
3X Searched by: Golden Gate Communications
    Mike Sweiss P:123 456 7890
 
---CAMBIUM NETWORKS---

SFP-10G-LR, NEW, qty 360, $52.95, CAMBIUM NETWORKS, Cambium Networks
SFP-10G-LR Searched by: Diversity IT LLC
    Jeremy Place P:123 456 7890
```

I am trying this with Python using regression technique to extract the data from text. But I am unable to identify how I can extract all the data for a particular column. The column name should be (Brand, MPN, Condition, Qty, Price, Search by, Customer name and phone number). I am attaching my code here. if anyone can help me out.

The format of text data are :

```
---Brand---

Product details

Contact details
```

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import re
def parse_email_content(email_content):

    # Regular expression patterns

    brand_pattern = r"---(.*?)---"

    product_pattern = r"(.*?), (.*?), qty (.*?), \$(.*?), (.*?), (.+)"

    contact_pattern = r"Searched by: (.+?)\n\s+(.+) P: (\S+)"

    data = []
    while email_content:
      reg_match = _RegExLib(email_content)

      if reg_match.brand_pattern:
        Brand = reg_match.brand_pattern.group(1)

      if reg_match.product_pattern:
        Product = reg_match.product_pattern.group(1)
        data['Product'] = data['Product'].str.split(',').str[0]

      if reg_match.contact_pattern:
        Contact_Person = reg_match.contact_pattern.group(1)

        dict_of_data = {
                        'Brand': brand_pattern,
                        'Product': product_pattern,
                        'Contact_Person': contact_pattern,
                        value_type: value
                    }
        data.append(dict_of_data)
        email_content = file.readline()

      email_content = file.readline()
    data = pd.DataFrame(data)
    data.set_index(['Brand', 'Product', 'Contact_Person'], inplace=True)
    return data
```

Comment: The columns required are: Brand, MPN, Condition, Qty, Price, Search By, Customer_name, ph number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse the data into a dataframe you can use following example:

```py
import re

import pandas as pd

text = """\
---ABB INSTALLATION PRODUCT---

54905BE06, NEW, qty 1687, $1.05, ABB INSTALLATION PRODUCT, *#6 1 hole
5490 Searched by: Gracile IT LLC
    Oliver Wilson P:123 456 7890

---ARUBA NETWORKS---

R1C72A, NEW, qty 21, $155.00, ARUBA NETWORKS, *AP mount bracketAruba
R1C72A Searched by: Synergy Associates, LLC
    N/A P:123 456 7890

---ATC CENTRAL SOURCING---

3X5HZYLBACKCOX, NEW, qty 353, $8.24, ATC CENTRAL SOURCING, The ATC Ce
3X Searched by: Golden Gate Communications
    Mike Sweiss P:123 456 7890

3X5HZYLPWRCOX, NEW, qty 353, $8.24, ATC CENTRAL SOURCING, The ATC Cen
3X Searched by: Golden Gate Communications
    Mike Sweiss P:123 456 7890

---CAMBIUM NETWORKS---

SFP-10G-LR, NEW, qty 360, $52.95, CAMBIUM NETWORKS, Cambium Networks
SFP-10G-LR Searched by: Diversity IT LLC
    Jeremy Place P:123 456 7890
"""

all_data = []
for name, group in re.findall(
    r"^---(.*?)---(.*?)\s*(?=^---|\Z)", text, flags=re.S | re.M
):
    m = re.search(
        r"(\S+)\s*,\s*(\S+),\s*qty\s*(\d+).*\$([^,\s]+).*?Searched by:\s*(.*?)\s*P:([^\n]+)",
        group,
        flags=re.S,
    )
    if m:
        mpn, condition, qty, price, customer_name, p_number = m.groups()
        search_by, customer_name = map(str.strip, customer_name.split("\n"))
        all_data.append(
            [name, mpn, condition, qty, price, search_by, customer_name, p_number]
        )

df = pd.DataFrame(
    all_data,
    columns=[
        "name",
        "mpn",
        "condition",
        "qty",
        "price",
        "search_by",
        "customer_name",
        "p_number",
    ],
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                       name             mpn condition   qty   price                   search_by  customer_name      p_number
0  ABB INSTALLATION PRODUCT       54905BE06       NEW  1687    1.05              Gracile IT LLC  Oliver Wilson  123 456 7890
1            ARUBA NETWORKS          R1C72A       NEW    21  155.00     Synergy Associates, LLC            N/A  123 456 7890
2      ATC CENTRAL SOURCING  3X5HZYLBACKCOX       NEW   353    8.24  Golden Gate Communications    Mike Sweiss  123 456 7890
3          CAMBIUM NETWORKS      SFP-10G-LR       NEW   360   52.95            Diversity IT LLC   Jeremy Place  123 456 7890
```

Comment: Thank you Andrej Kesely for your quick support, there are some changes in the data. Could you please help again. I have tried to sorted that, but I was unsuccessful. Also, If possible, could you please comment out the lines of code so that I can figure out where I made the mistake.

Comment: @SanjeetKumar I've updated the answer. There's also [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/CMGAGr/1) that explains the inner regex.

Comment: If we have to add another column, lets say Email column as it is given in the input field, then changing the 
m = re.search(
        r"(\S+)\s*,\s*(\S+),\s*qty\s*(\d+).*\$([^,\s]+).*?Searched by:\s*(.*?)\s*P:([^\n]+)",
        group,
        flags=re.S,
    )
will work?